# MongoDB query response is too slow

Tags: mongodb, mgo

I am working on a Golang project (db MongoDB). I have executed the below query but it is taking too much time to load the data. In this, I am getting data from 2 collections with multiple stages.

```
db.getCollection('Collection1').aggregate([
{
    "$lookup": {
        "localField": "uid",
        "from": "collection2",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "user_info"
    }
},
{
    "$unwind": "$user_info"
},
{
    "$lookup": {
        "localField": "cid",
        "from": "collection3",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "cust_info"
    }
},
{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "logs",
        "let":  {"id": "$_id"},
        "pipeline": [
                {"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$$id", "$log_id"]}}},
                {"$sort": {"log_type": 1}}],
        "as": "logs_data"
    }
},
{
    "$sort": {"logs_data.logged_on":-1}
},
{
    "$skip": 1
},
{
    "$limit": 2
},
])
```

My requirement is to add 2 time sort within the same query:

1. Within the logs array `"$sort": {"log_type": 1}}`
2. For the end result `"$sort": {"logs_data.logged_on":-1}`

For this I have tries the following indexes:

```
{"logged_on" : -1}
{"log_id":1, "log_type":1}
```

But the query taking still 6-7 sec to execute.

If I remove `"$sort": {"logs_data.logged_on":-1}` then it works fast but with this sorting it is taking too much time.

how and what can I do to improve the response time.

Comment: Will the `logs` collection contain any documents that don't match an `_id` from `collection1`?

Comment: @Joe No It is not possible. Logs does not contain any document that don't match the "_id" from collection1

Answer (score 0):

What that aggregation is doing:

1. retrieve all documents from collection1
2. for each document in collection1, find a single document in collection2
3. for each document in collection1, find a single document in collection3
4. for each document in collection1, find all realated documents in logs
5. for each document in collection1, perform an in-memory sort of the documents retrieved from logs
6. perform an in-memory sort to order the documents
7. keep 2 of these documents and discard the rest

For each document in collection1 that is 3 document fetches (plus the unknown number of fetches in #4), 2 index scans, and an in-memory sort.

If there is a non-trivial amount of documents in collection1, that is a ton of work, which is wasted for all but 2 of the documents.

If it is safe to assume that every document in `logs` contains a `log_id` that maps back to `collection1`, you could:

- create an index on `{logged_on:1, log_id:1}`
- start the aggregation on the logs collection
- sort by `logged_on: 1`
- project `{logged_on:1, log_id:1, _id:0}` (this makes the first part of the aggregation fully covered by the above index)
- group by `log_id`, taking the `$first` value of `logged_on`
- sort by `logged_on: 1` (grouping distrubs the sort)
- skip and limit as desired
- lookup from `collection1` with local `log_id` foreign `_id`
- replaceRoot with the newRoot being the looked up document
- execute the existing pipeline stages you were using - this time they will only be fetching/sorting for the 2 documents you want to return.